# Blazor, event listener as inline delegate or handler in @functions section

Tags: events, listener, blazor

I got different reaction (output in console) when using inline delegate or when implementing a handler in @functions section. I don't understand why! Is that a bug or something is missing me?

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="@(e => Console.Write(e.Key))" />
```

It gives me immediate output in console.
But when I use a handler like this, I got nothing:

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="@showKey"/>
@functions{
    void showKey(UIKeyboardEventArgs e){
        Console.Write(e.Key);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both don't work for me with your code. But do work when I change them to `Console.WriteLine(e.key)`

I guess `Console.Write` is not supported because browsers don't support this, `Console.Writeline` translates to `console.log` and `Console.Write` has nothing to translate to.

Comment: Yes, I mixed WriteLine and Write, so I got  confused. It seems that Write is not supported. Thank you very much.

Comment: Nice. it fails silently, that makes it hard to track down.